# Discord music bot discord.player.FFmpegPCMAudio() argument after ** must be a mapping

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

my problem is that when I type !play music (example: !play Rickroll) sends to the discord chat what's playing, starts downloading, but that crashes:

It joins vc (!join), sends
ERROR:

```
[youtube] NvZMy6xaYcQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video NvZMy6xaYcQ because of --no-playlist
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "g:\code\hudba\music_cog.py", line 174, in play
    await self.play_music(ctx)
  File "g:\code\hudba\music_cog.py", line 134, in play_music
    self.vc[id].play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
TypeError: discord.player.FFmpegPCMAudio() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: discord.player.FFmpegPCMAudio() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set
```

This is cog file to play music:

```
import discord
from discord_components import Select, SelectOption, Button
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio
from asyncio import run_coroutine_threadsafe
from urllib import parse, request
import re
import json
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.is_playing = {}
        self.is_paused = {}
        self.music_queue = {}
        self.queueIndex = {}
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {format: 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options:' '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options' '-vn'} 

        self.embedBlue = 0x2c76dd
        self.embedRed = 0xdf1147
        self.embedGreen = 0x0eaa51

        self.vc = {}
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Ready ----------------------------------")
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            id = int(guild.id)
            self.music_queue[id] = []
            self.queueIndex[id] = 0
            self.vc[id] = None
            self.is_paused[id] = self.is_playing[id] = False     

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
        id = int(member.guild.id)
        if member.id != self.bot.user.id and before.channel != None and after.channel != before.channel:
            remainingChannelMembers = before.channel.members
            if len(remainingChannelMembers) == 1 and remainingChannelMembers[0].id == self.bot.user.id and self.vc[id].is_connected():
                self.is_playing[id] = self.is_paused[id] = False
                self.music_queue[id] = []
                self.queueIndex[id] = 0
                await self.vc[id].disconnect()


    def now_playing_embed(self, ctx, song):
        title = song['title']
        link = song['link']
        thumbnail = song['thumbnail']
        author= ctx.author
        avatar = author.avatar_url

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Now Playing",
            description=f'[{title}],({link})',
            colour=self.embedBlue,
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Song pustil: {str(author)}', icon_url=avatar)
        return embed

    async def join_vc(self, ctx, channel):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        if self.vc[id] == None or not self.vc[id].is_connected():
            self.vc[id] = await channel.connect()

            if self.vc[id] == None:
                await ctx.send("Nepodařilo se připojit do VOICU")
                return
        else:
            await self.vc[id].move_to(channel)

    def search_YT(self, search):
        queryString = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
        htmContent = request.urlopen(
            'http://www.youtube.com/results?' + queryString)
        searchResults = re.findall(
            '/watch\?v=(.{11})', htmContent.read().decode())
        return searchResults[0:10]

    def extract_YT(self, url):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            except:
                return False
            
        return {
                    'link': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + url,
                    'thumbnail': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + url + '/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOADEI4CSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLD5uL4xKN-IUfez6KIW_j5y70mlig',
                    'source': info['formats'][0]['url'],
                    'title': info['title']
        }
    def play_next(self, ctx):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        if not self.is_playing[id]:
            return
        if self.queueIndex[id] +1   < len(self.music_queue[id]):
            self.is_playing[id] = True
            self.queueIndex[id] += 1

            song = self.music_queue[id][self.queueIndex[id]][0]
            message = self.now_playing_embed(ctx, song)
            coro = ctx.send(embed=message)
            fut = run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, self.bot.loop)
            try:
                fut.result()
            except:
                pass
            self.vc[id].play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
                song['link'], **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
        else:
            self.queueIndex[id] += 1
            self.is_playing[id] = False


    async def play_music(self,ctx):
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        if self.queueIndex[id] < len(self.music_queue[id]):
            self.is_playing[id] = True
            self.is_paused[id] = False

            await self.join_vc(ctx ,self.music_queue[id][self.queueIndex[id]][1])

            song = self.music_queue[id][self.queueIndex[id]][0]
            message = self.now_playing_embed(ctx, song)
            await ctx.send(embed=message)

            self.vc[id].play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
                song['link'], **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx))
        else:
            await ctx.send("Ve Frontě už není co dál pustit. Pusť tam další songu!")
            self.queueIndex[id] += 1
            self.is_playing[id] = False
    
    @ commands.command(
        name="play",
        aliases=["pl"],
        help = "Připojí bota do VOICE ROOMKY"
    )
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        search = " ".join(args)
        id = int(ctx.guild.id)
        try:
            userChannel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        except:
            await ctx.send("Musíš být ve VOICE")
            return 
        if not args:
            if len(self.music_queue[id]) == 0:
                await ctx.send("Ve Frontě už není co dál pustit. Pusť tam další songu!")
            elif not self.is_playing[id]:
                if self.music_queue[id] == None or self.vc[id] == None:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)
                else:
                    self.is_paused[id] = False
                    self.is_playing[id] = True
                    self.vc[id].resume()
            else:
                return
        else:
            song = self.extract_YT(self.search_YT(search)[0])
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Nepodařilo se pustit songu. Zkus zadat jiný název.")
            else:
                self.music_queue[id].append([song, userChannel])

                if not self.is_playing[id]:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)
                else:
                    message = "Mes"
                    await ctx.send(embed=message)


    @ commands.command(
        name="join",
        aliases=["j"],
        help = "Připojí bota do VOICE ROOMKY"
    )
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice:
            userChannel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await self.join_vc(ctx, userChannel)
            await ctx.send(f"Hudbot se připojil {userChannel}")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Musíš být připojen ve VOICU")
```

Main file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import ComponentsBot

from music_cog import music_cog
from help_cog import help_cog

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

bot.remove_command('help')
bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))




bot.run('token')
```

List of downloaded modules: (libraries)

`` `Package                    Version ``

`-------------------------- -----------`

`aiohttp                    3.7.4.post0`

`aiosignal                  1.3.1`

`async-timeout              3.0.1`

`attrs                      22.1.0`

`cffi                       1.15.1`

`chardet                    4.0.0`

`charset-normalizer         2.1.1`

`colorama                   0.4.6`

`contourpy                  1.0.6`

`cookies-discord-components 3.0.0`

`cycler                     0.11.0`

`DateTime                   4.8`

`discord                    2.1.0`

`discord-components         2.1.2`

`discord.py                 1.7.3`

`ffmpeg                     1.4`

`fonttools                  4.38.0`

`frozenlist                 1.3.3`

`idna                       3.4`

`kiwisolver                 1.4.4`

`matplotlib                 3.6.2`

`mpmath                     1.2.1`

`multidict                  6.0.3`

`numpy                      1.24.0`

`packaging                  22.0`

`Pillow                     9.3.0`

`pip                        22.3.1`

`pycparser                  2.21`

`PyNaCl                     1.4.0`

`pyparsing                  3.0.9`

`python-dateutil            2.8.2`

`python-dotenv              0.15.0`

`pytz                       2022.6`

`scipy                      1.9.3`

`setuptools                 58.1.0`

`six                        1.16.0`

`termcolor                  2.1.1`

`typing_extensions          4.4.0`

`urllib3                    1.26.13`

`yarl                       1.8.2`

`youtube-dl                 2021.12.17`

`zope.interface             5.5.2`

`PS G:\code> pip install ffmpeg`

`` Requirement already satisfied: ffmpeg in e:\lib\site-packages (1.4)` ``

I don't know what's wrong and how to fix it. Im lost.

sorry for my bad english, not enough practise :)

I tried lots of things, but didn't work. If you could help me i would be so happy :)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS` reads as the following:

```py
{'before_options:' '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options' '-vn'}
```

This isn't a dictionary, but instead it is a set.
Through implicit string concatenation Python would transform this to the following:

```py
{'before_options:-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options-vn'}
```

The syntax to create a dictionary in Python is:

- `d = dict(key=value)`
- `d = {key: value}`

Comment: Didn't help :l
still this error:
`Command raised an exception: TypeError: discord.player.FFmpegPCMAudio() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set`

Comment: @NoMexukradokap What exactly did you change? Can you please comment the definition of `self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS`?